# Using git tag to save the state of the repository

Tags: git

I have been doing some reading about git tags and I think I am a little confused in my head. I see tags can be used for commit. So, assume here is whats happening in my repo.,

Commit - C1
        Commit - C2
        Commit - C3
        Commit - C4
        Commit - C5

At this time, say 5 commits were made into the repo. If I run git tag -a TagV1.0 -m "first tag", that creates a tag that basically saves the current state of repo, right? All files as in at the moment of running this command, not just files in Commit C5. Will it be a snapshot of the repo at the moment of running the command?

After I created the tag.
       Commit - C6 came in. If I do git tag -a -f TagV1.0 -m "Updating tag". This includes all commits and then C6 as well. Is that right?

After I created the tag, if Commit 6,7,8 came in. Can I force update the tag to include only 7 and not 6 and 8?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tag does not, by itself, save the state of the repository.  In fact, it does not *save* anything at all,<sup>1,3</sup> unless you consider "jotting down the SHA-1 of the current commit" to be "saving" something:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f
```

The 40-character "number" above is the current commit.  All `git tag` does is write this into a file somewhere.<sup>2</sup>

To really understand this, you need to know:

- Every commit is "forever".<sup>3</sup>  Its "true name", the big ugly SHA-1, uniquely identifies that commit, and *only* that commit.  The SHA-1 is actually a crypographic checksum of the contents of the commit, including the time stamps for when the commit is made, the author name and email, and so on.
- Each commit includes the raw SHA-1 of its parent commit(s).  This is how, starting from commit `C5`, git can find `C4`: `C5` contains the true name of `C4`, as part of `C5`'s own contents.  Then `C4` lets git find `C3`, and so on.
- As far as git is concerned, any reference name—the major obvious ones are branch and tag names, but there are lots of other forms of references—is just a way to come up with a starting SHA-1.

When you (or git) stores one of these SHA-1 true-names inside various items—repository objects like commits, or files named according to a tag or branch name, or whatever—we say that this "points to" the object whose true-name you store.  So `C5` points to `C4`, and `C4` points to `C3`, and so on.

Thus, if you have a tag pointing to `C5`, and you do anything to create new commits in the repository, the tag still just points to `C5`.<sup>4</sup>  If you want to make it point somewhere else—such as your new commit `C6`—you must delete the old one and make a new one (or, really, just overwrite the contents of the file, as long as it's in its own private file and not shared like the packed refs in footnote 2).

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not entirely true: an *annotated* tag saves the annotation in the repository, and then has the corresponding lightweight tag point to the newly-saved object.  The annotated tag in the repository has its own SHA-1, and contains, as part of the annotation, the SHA-1 of whatever you're tagging.

<sup>2</sup>The file is `.git/refs/tags/tagname`, but eventually this can get "packed" and moved into `.git/packed-refs` along with other references.

<sup>3</sup>Well, almost.  A commit, or indeed any git repository object, with no *incoming* references is eligible for garbage collection.  This means that each reference actually does two things: give you a name for a raw SHA-1, and—at least potentially—*protect* the object that this SHA-1 names, saving it from the Grim Collector.  In that particular sense, a tag could be said to "save" things—but typically, the tag name is just *one* way to reach that commit.  For instance, after you make `C6`, you can reach `C5` by starting from the branch name and moving to its parent; that's sufficient to protect `C5`.

<sup>4</sup>This should make you stop and wonder: hey, wait, then how does my *branch* automatically include my new commit `C6` once I make it?  The answer is: git automatically deletes and re-creates it, as part of the process of making commit `C6`.  That's really what makes a branch name special: you can tell git "get on this branch", which git does by writing the branch name down somewhere,<sup>5</sup> and then when you make new commits, git sees that you're on that branch and automatically updates the reference-file.

<sup>5</sup>Specifically, it writes the current branch name in the file `.git/HEAD`.  So `git rev-parse HEAD`, as shown above, reads the `HEAD` file, finds that it names a branch, and then reads the branch file, and now git has the raw SHA-1 "true name" for the current commit.  Or, if you ask git which branch you're on, it reads the `HEAD` file, finds that it names a branch, and stops there and prints out the branch name.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did my playing around in some local repos but this detailed explanation definitely helped me. Appreciate a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

In git each commit is a complete snapshot of the repository. A tag is just that, a mark that allows to identify some commit.

If, as you say, you want to include other commits, you just have to remove the tag and create a new tag in the desired commit.

Comment: In git each commit is a complete snapshot of the repository.